# Number of 1 bits in a decimal number

Tags: haskell

How can I write a function to return the number of 1 bits corresponding a decimal number? Maybe a square root function? The type should be this:

```
bits :: Int -> Int
```

EDIT: SOlved

```
uns :: Int -> Int
uns  0 = 0
uns 1 = 1
uns x | mod x 2 == 1 = 1 + uns (div x 2)
      | otherwise = uns (div x 2)
```

Comment: [popCount](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Bits.html#v:popCount)

Comment: What has square root got to do with anything? Just examine each of the bits. I don't know about haskell, but in C you would AND the value with 0x01 to examine bit 0, AND it with 0x02 to examine bit 1, etc. Or you could shift through it a bit at a time always looking at the new bit 0.

Comment: How would you determine whether the least-significant bit were 1 or 0? How can you achieve a bit-shift without using a shift operator like `>>` from C?

Comment: **hint**: [`divMod`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:divMod) probably with `2` somewhere ;) - aside from this you should tell us a bit about what you tried so far, where did you hit a wall? Do you know how to do it with pen and paper let's say for `119`?

Comment: i know the logic behind it, i mean, i don't know how to do it, but i know there must be a way to do it correctly without using the shift operator. that's how i'd like to do it...

Comment: ok: another hint: `119 = 2*59+1` so you have one `1` bit in there - `59 = 29*2+1` so another one, `29=2*14+1` yep one more, `14=2*7+0` well this time no luck, ...

Comment: @AlexanderVieth assuming that was directed at me - as I said, I don't know haskell. I'm assuming from your context that the bit shift operator doesn't exist however you said nothing addressing an AND operator so I assume it exists. To test the LSB, test if value AND 1 == 0 (off) or 1 (on). To schieve bit shifting, multiply or divide by 2 (for left / right shift respectively).

Comment: @mah Nope, that was directed at Ricz S :) Was trying to nudge him in the right direction.

Answer (score 7):

What about this old trick?

```
import Data.Bits

countOnes 0 = 0
countOnes x = 1 + countOnes (x .&. (x-1))
```

It only recurses *n* times where *n* is the number of one bits in *x*.

Of course, if you are going to import `Data.Bits`, then you might as well use `popCount` as @Cirdec suggested.

Answer (score 5):

Use `popCount` from `Data.Bits`, also known as the *Hamming weight* of a number.  The advantage is that some CPUs have instructions specifically for calculating this, resulting in high performance.

```
λ> import Data.Bits
λ> :t popCount
popCount :: Bits a => a -> Int
λ> popCount 255
8
λ> popCount 0xa5
4
```

Answer (score 4):

```
sum . map (`mod` 2) . takeWhile ( /= 0) . iterate (`quot` 2)
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess Luka has the better version but maybe you struggle a bit with understanding it, so here is what I hinted at (which is the same Luka did only with naive recursion):

```
bits :: Int -> Int
bits 0 = 0
bits n = let (d,r) = n `divMod` 2
         in r + bits d
```

The idea is to get continous divide by 2 and look at the remainder - if it's 1 then you found a set bit, if not (it has to be 0 then) then there was none.